# Do I seal just the grout or the tiles and grout?

Tags: sealing, grout, ceramic-tile, tiling

I just tiled the bathtub alcove and it came out great.  Now I need to seal the grout. My question is, do i seal just the grout lines or do I apply the seal on the tiles and the grout?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This greatly depends on the type tile you have. If it is a manmade tile such as porcelain, or ceramic, then you don't have to worry about sealing it.

Most natural stone tiles, especially softer or water permeable stone such as marble, limestone/travertine, and slate should be sealed as well. This would ideally be done prior to grouting to prevent the stone from being stained by the grout. It would also be a good idea to use an unsanded grout with natural stone, especially marble because the sand from the grout could leave scratches in the surface.

Comment: I have ceramic. Thnaks

Comment: There are porcelain and ceramic tiles that have a crackle finish that also need sealing.

Comment: @bib I have standard smooth finish. Thanks for that info though.